# Delete trailing space from all values

Tags: oracle, delete-row, sql-delete

I have a table that contains more than 4 thousand rows.  Suppose I have a column named columnname that has values for all rows but each value may have leading and/or trailing blank characters.  So, it might look like this

```
columname
"value "
"value "
"value "
...
```

And I need a query or technique that removes the leading and/or trailing spaces, like this:

```
columname
"value"
"value"
"value"
```

How can I achieve this? (I use oracle 11g)

Comment: So you want to trim all char fields, AND delete any rows whose columns are all whitespace?  (and 4000 rows is a huge table?)

Comment: is it not enough huge for you ? no I want to delete just blank characters in all rows

Comment: Great question for stackoverflow imo!  It showed up in my google search as exactly what I was looking for and the answer below is also exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll try to improve the grammar of the question to convey your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET columnname = TRIM( columnname );
```

followed by

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE columnname IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just this:

```
Update table set columnname = trim(columnname)
```